# displaying edit and object mode together

Tags: 3d-view

I think It'd be very useful to show the edit mode in one viewport and the object mode in another viewport, but this is not available as a feature, Is there are any workaround to achieve this?

Comment: Why would it be useful?

Comment: Yeah really why would it be useful? You can see the same shape in edit mode

Comment: he means that he wants to see it in both ways in splitted windows

Comment: @MichaelBenDavid But Why?

Comment: Complicated geometry can often only be manipulated in a certain plane but the result is best realised in another. Or simply the change in geometry is being made solely to alter the shading.

Comment: @cegaton, the wires in edit mode can be sometimes distracting when editing